# please help to deaf sotware engineers

Tags: communication

I'm partially deaf but i can able to speak in mobile and others near to me... I completed B.E computer science engg.. I can't able to get a job. because previous  i worked in IT company as the position of programmer.. In a meeting I'm afraid because i can't answer the question.. so, the people complaint to me mentioned on deaf reason.. so I relieved from it... Now , I confused for what i do...
please tell some ideas what the ways to communicate in meeting for software programmer...

kindly i will wish to you....

please tell me

Comment: @gnat I think there is just a very subtle difference between that question and this one.  This one is more about how to approach the recruitment/interviewing process while the other is about how to improve communication while already within the workplace.  I would however suggest that question would be a very good place to start _after_ the OP manages to get a job :)

Comment: I don't know what your written skills in your native language are, but your English is unclear. One thing you need to do when you have a problem  communicating because you are deaf is to make sure you can clearly communicate in writing because that is going to be one of your main methods of communicating.

Answer (score 6):

Being partially or completely deaf should not be so much of an impediment to an understanding organization.  I would suggest being up front about your hearing issues at the time you are offered an interview. Note I would *not* raise it beforehand.  You should be evaluated on your merits to get shortlisted.  In an interview situation, just ensure the panel knows so they can make allowances for it.

Remember, on a day to day basis as a developer, much of your interactions are done via email or IM.  It should not be such a big imposition on an organization to cater for, if you are otherwise the best candidate.

As an aside, a few years ago a company we colocated with had a developer who was completely blind.  He was one of the best developers I've ever come across. :)

Another aside: my daughter is hearing impaired.  It took just a little adjustment  for us to adapt :)